# How would I allow a C# Application to connect to an Azure SQL database without having to add the IP address to the firewall every time

Tags: c#, ip, azure-sql-database, firewall

I am building a C# WPF application that's connected to Microsoft Azures SQL database. I'm passing a connection string to the application and that allows the app to talk to the database.

The problem with this is that I would have to go into azure and add the client's current IP address every time I install the app on a new computer or in a new location. I guess a better question is, how do I make it so the application allows all IP addresses to access the DataBase without any security issues?

The application is going to be private and installed within the company only, So I'm not worried about outsiders getting their hands on the application

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure), you can specify a *range* of IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said this a private company application, but I would suggest building a simple Web API the handles all of your database communications to improve security.

As Robert mentioned in the comments you can add a range of IP addresses. This will be fairly easy too since all of your client's web traffic should go through a small range of addresses.

Comment: We use a Web API to address connections to ~250 Azure SQL Database customer databases.